# Parallax + slant on Chrome / webkit

Tags: css, webkit, transform, parallax, skew

I'm trying to add a CSS slant to `<section>` elements on my page, which also serve as backgrounds for a "parallax" scrolling effect.

I'm encountering an interesting problem. The slant works on the first `<section>`, but on the second (or any after that), the background image is moved down, or the flow of the div gets messed up. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3est/7/embedded/result/) of the problem. Any ideas?

If you open the fiddle in Safari, that's the behavior I'm expecting.

**Update**: It actually has nothing to do with the parallax scrolling. It's just the combination of background-attachment: fixed and slant.